# Created a partition for CentOS 8 and can no longer boot Windows 10

Tags: centos, partition, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I had a Windows 10 PC and wanted to create a CentOS 8 partition. I shrank the memory of the current partition and left ~100 GB to install CentOS into. Upon installation I selected the partition and CentOS 8 works perfect.

However when rebooting there is no option to boot back into windows. I have checked and my Windows partition is still there.

```
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA SanDisk SSD PLUS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: pmbr_boot

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  556MB   555MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      556MB   661MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      661MB   677MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      677MB   895GB   895GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      895GB   895GB   1049kB                                             bios_grub
 6      895GB   896GB   1074MB  xfs
 7      896GB   1000GB  104GB                                              lvm

(parted)
```

Furthermore, `os-prober` returns nothing.

I have also tried `yum update grub2` and rebooted without success.

I found that `ls /sys/firmware/efi` returns nothing which I believe indicates my boot mode is BIOS. I don't know if this is problematic?

I am pretty new to linux so am a little overwhelmed atm. Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1: Contents of the grub.cfg file**

```
#                                                                                                                     
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                     
# It is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates                                                     
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub                                                                
#                                                                                                                     

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###                                                                                   
set pager=1

if [ -f ${config_directory}/grubenv ]; then
  load_env -f ${config_directory}/grubenv
elif [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="${saved_entry}"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

terminal_output console
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is                                                   
# unavailable.                                                                                                        
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###                                                                                     

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###                                                                                    
set tuned_params=""
set tuned_initrd=""
### END /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###                                                                                      

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/01_users ###                                                                                    
if [ -f ${prefix}/user.cfg ]; then
  source ${prefix}/user.cfg
  if [ -n "${GRUB2_PASSWORD}" ]; then
    set superusers="root"
    export superusers
    password_pbkdf2 root ${GRUB2_PASSWORD}
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/01_users ###        

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/08_fallback_counting ###                                                                        
insmod increment
# Check if boot_counter exists and boot_success=0 to activate this behaviour.                                         
if [ -n "${boot_counter}" -a "${boot_success}" = "0" ]; then
  # if countdown has ended, choose to boot rollback deployment,                                                       
  # i.e. default=1 on OSTree-based systems.                                                                           
  if  [ "${boot_counter}" = "0" -o "${boot_counter}" = "-1" ]; then
    set default=1
    set boot_counter=-1
  # otherwise decrement boot_counter                                                                                  
  else
    decrement boot_counter
  fi
  save_env boot_counter
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/08_fallback_counting ###                                                                          

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###                                                                                    
insmod part_gpt
insmod xfs
set root='hd0,gpt6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6 --hint\
='hd0,gpt6'  d41234e5-75e2-4f90-8ac6-79015ed23c9c
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d41234e5-75e2-4f90-8ac6-79015ed23c9c
fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod xfs
set boot='hd0,gpt6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=boot --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6 --hint\
='hd0,gpt6'  d41234e5-75e2-4f90-8ac6-79015ed23c9c
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=boot d41234e5-75e2-4f90-8ac6-79015ed23c9c
fi

# This section was generated by a script. Do not modify the generated file - all changes                              
# will be lost the next time file is regenerated. Instead edit the BootLoaderSpec files.                              
#                                                                                                                     
# The blscfg command parses the BootLoaderSpec files stored in /boot/loader/entries and                               
# populates the boot menu. Please refer to the Boot Loader Specification documentation                                
# for the files format: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/BootLoaderSpec/.                              

# The kernelopts variable should be defined in the grubenv file. But to ensure that menu                              
# entries populated from BootLoaderSpec files that use this variable work correctly even                              
# without a grubenv file, define a fallback kernelopts variable if this has not been set.                             
#                                                                                                                     
# The kernelopts variable in the grubenv file can be modified using the grubby tool or by                             
# executing the grub2-mkconfig tool. For the latter, the values of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX                             
# and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT options from /etc/default/grub file are used to set both                             
# the kernelopts variable in the grubenv file and the fallback kernelopts variable.   

if [ -z "${kernelopts}" ]; then
  set kernelopts="root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv\
=cl/swap rhgb quiet "
fi

insmod blscfg
blscfg
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###                                                                                      

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_reset_boot_success ###                                                                       
# Hiding the menu is ok if last boot was ok or if this is a first boot attempt to boot the entry                      
if [ "${boot_success}" = "1" -o "${boot_indeterminate}" = "1" ]; then
  set menu_hide_ok=1
else
  set menu_hide_ok=0
fi
# Reset boot_indeterminate after a successful boot                                                                    
if [ "${boot_success}" = "1" ] ; then
  set boot_indeterminate=0
# Avoid boot_indeterminate causing the menu to be hidden more then once                                               
elif [ "${boot_indeterminate}" = "1" ]; then
  set boot_indeterminate=2
fi
# Reset boot_success for current boot                                                                                 
set boot_success=0
save_env boot_success boot_indeterminate
### END /etc/grub.d/10_reset_boot_success ###                                                                         

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/12_menu_auto_hide ###                                                                           
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  if [ "${menu_show_once}" ]; then
    unset menu_show_once
    save_env menu_show_once
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=60
  elif [ "${menu_auto_hide}" -a "${menu_hide_ok}" = "1" ]; then
    set orig_timeout_style=${timeout_style}
    set orig_timeout=${timeout}
    if [ "${fastboot}" = "1" ]; then
      # timeout_style=menu + timeout=0 avoids the countdown code keypress check                                       
      set timeout_style=menu
      set timeout=0
    else
      set timeout_style=hidden
      set timeout=1
    fi
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/12_menu_auto_hide ###
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it’s nice to get grub working, however, since you said that /sys/firmware/efi is empty, that means you installed Centos8 using a legacy boot loader, however I see a UEFI volume for windows, meaning Windows needs to boot via UEFI.  Windows installed as EFI won’t boot if you launch it from GRUB legacy.

You need to convert your CentOS 8 system to use UEFI, or reinstall booting the installer as EFI instead of as a legacy boot disk.